# Join on nonexact values

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables - 1) A list of business names with primary identification fields and 2) A heading table.

Most records in my database are receiving a header when they come in but some are not classified. I was hoping to find a way to join my primary table business name on a header from my table that has the list of headers. The problem is I don't know how to do a join where it is not exact but rather a regex. Example

```
Table 1: 
Business Name
Bobs Accounting Firm

Table 2:
Header
Accounting Firm
```

I want to find a way where I could match these up so I could assign all the businesses with the header that is included within its name.

So Kindof thinking it would go something like this

```
select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.stdname = t2.header (but the regex) version
```

....

Not sure if this is possible or if it makes sense but thanks for the help

Comment: `join` operations just boil down to a boolean operation: if the join conditions return true, then the records are joined. so any regex you write that can boil down to a true/false result can be used in a join. e.g. `join foo on foo.bar regexp 'baz'`

Comment: Can you post larger sample of rows from each table so we can get an idea of what kinds of variance there is between them? Based on the one row shown, you could just do a substring match which would be faster than a regexp.

Comment: You will pay a price to run the regex every time you perform the join.  Why not have a routine that classifies the unclassified headers instead?